# How to print strings from a list of hash sets

Tags: c#, list, hash

How to print the items of a list of hashsets in c#?

```
private List<HaShet <string>> n = new List<HashSet<string>>();
```

Comment: Are you expecting a union or a concatenation between the hash sets?

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ to isolate all the strings:

```
IEnumerable<string> allStrings = 
    n.SelectMany(list => list);
```

With this sequence you are free to do whatever you like, including to print all of them.

You can leverage LINQ to perform other operations with strings before printing them as well. For example, to remove duplicates you can use `Distinct`, and to sort them you can use `OrderBy`:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = 
    n.SelectMany(list => list)
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(s => s);
```